# Scalaz validation: convert sequence of validations to a single validation

Tags: scala, validation, scalaz

I am using scalaz validation, and have some code to validate products.

```
def validateProduct(product: Option[Product]): ValidationNel[String, Product] = ???
```

Given a list of products, I want to get a single validation containing the whole list as a successful value or a list of validation errors. It seems like some kind of fold should do it, but I am not sure what the combination function should be.

```
 def validateProducts(products: Seq[Option[Product]]): ValidationNel[String, Seq[Product]] = {
    val listOfValidations: Seq[ValidationNel[String, Product]] = products.map(validateProduct _)
    val validatedList:ValidationNel[Seq[String], Seq[Product]] = ??? // what to do here?
    ???
  }
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If instead of a `ValidationNel[List[String], List[Product]]` you want a `ValidationNel[String, List[Product]]` (i.e., all the failures in the same list), you can just use `traverse`:

```
val result: ValidationNel[String, List[Product]] =
  products.toList.traverseU(validateProduct)
```

Note that I've converted the `Seq` to a `List` as there are no type class instances for raw `Seq`, and I'm using `traverseU` rather than `traverse` as Scala's type inference doesn't quite work for non-trivial type constructors like `ValidationNel`

Comment: Very clean solution

Answer (score 7):

You can use fold with applicative

```
  import scalaz.syntax.validation._
  import scalaz.syntax.applicative._

  case class Product(name: String)

  val allGood = Seq(
    Product("a").successNel[String],
    Product("b").successNel[String]
  )

  val aggregated: ValidationNel[String, Seq[Product]] = 
    allGood.foldLeft(Seq.empty[Product].successNel[String]) {
    case (acc , v) => (acc |@| v)(_ :+ _)
  }

  println(aggregated)
```